# Помощь в контакте удалённого сервера и локального репо

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, openssh

Я на VSCode с помощью плагина развернул удалённый репо с сервера, каким образом мне сделать чтобы при редактировании он менялся сразу же?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как мне кажется, вам надо копать и наращивать понимание в том как работать с git (системой контроля версий) и "удалённым сервером" -- удалённым репозиторием, таким как github. Просто поищите простые мануалы. "Github шпаргалка" -- типовой запрос для этого.

Comment: менялся сразу же -- это сразу же заливался на удалённый репозиторий? Так нельзя делать. Это можно осуществить баш-скриптами, но это противоречит идее репозитория, куда идёт уже проверенный код. Или сразу же работал на локальном сервере при правках в VSCode? Тогда вам нужен Hot Reload -- он встроен в webpack. Есть аналоги для других сборщиков.